# Safari browser zooming + linear-gradient issue

Tags: css, safari, zooming, scaling, linear-gradients

I'm using a

```css
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0 47px,  #000 47px 48px); 
background-size(48px);
```

to draw 1px vertical lines on the background.
It works correctly everywhere, and in Safari as well, except in the case when Safari browser is zoomed in.

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/7s1af36g/2/

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0 47px,  #000 47px 48px);
  background-size: 48px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

That's how it looks in safari venture 16.3 with 110% zoom:

[image: thick gradient lines instead of 1px]

Also, the lines completely disappear when the browser is zoomed out.

[image]

Is there any workaround-fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: one possible solution is to use the CSS zoom property to prevent the zoom applying to the background

This property is [not supported in FF](https://caniuse.com/css-zoom) and MDN has a [fairly strong advisement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) not to use the `reset` value, but it does prevent your issue in Safari - in this fiddle I've added `zoom: reset` to your BG elements but not your SQ elemenets - so zoom is essentially disabled for the BG in safari, but the SQ elements will still scale up. Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbwn4tuh/

**Previous answer:**

I'm not entirely sure why Safari is behaving differently, but adding an extra transparent step to the gradient (covering the pixels after your vertical line) from `49px` to `100%` seems to resolve the issue in Safari when zooming.

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0 47px, #000 47px 48px, transparent 49px 100%);
  background-size: 48px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: It helps, but just a bit. Yes, the gradient becomes closer to 1px width when zoomed in. But zooming out still makes it completely white. And background-position seems to work incorrectly as well. I created another example, https://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/s9o127r3/3/, there're just a few overlaying divs. They all should be aligned, but zooming in in safari looks like a total crap.

Comment: It's a very odd issue, I just edited my answer to include a workaround using the CSS zoom property. It's not ideal as it disabled zoom on the element it's attached too entirely, but might be an acceptable compromise since it does seem to fix your issue visually in Safari